# Creating records per a record in C#

Tags: c#, sql

- I want to create records in a single record.
- For Example:

**Order #0001** will have

```
Color: 1,4,6,8
PCs: 6,4,3
Cutting, 30-25,30
```

**Order #0002**

will be different than order #0001

```
Color: 2,8,7,9
PCs: 3,1,2
Cutting, 25-30,40
```

- as I navigate through order numbers, it will show me different customer name and their order details.
- I will enter order details and press "Add to Order" it will go to datagridview below, once all the order is complete, I will press "Submit Order" this is One complete record.

  - When I press "New Order" the order goes below in the datagridview instead of creating an entirely new order without any data in DataGridView.

[image]

This is my code below:

```
void AddRecords()
    {
                Connection con = new OrderManager.Connection();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                string query = @"INSERT INTO [MasterDatabase].[dbo].[Neworder]
        ([OrderID]
        ,[Date]
        ,[Customer_Name]
        ,[Quality]
        ,[Color]
        ,[PCs]
        ,[Cutting]
        ,[TotalYards])
VALUES
        (@OrderID
        ,@Date
        ,@Customer_Name
        ,@Quality
        ,@Color
        ,@PCs
        ,@Cutting
        ,@TotalYards)";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con.ActiveCon());
            pcs = Convert.ToInt32(updown_PCs.Text);
            cutting = Convert.ToInt32(combo_Cutting.Text);
            total_yards = pcs * cutting;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", TxtBox_OrderID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Name", txtbox_CusName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quality", combo_Quality.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color", combo_Color.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCs", updown_PCs.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cutting", combo_Cutting.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalYards", total_yards);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted", "Record Entered Successfully!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        else { MessageBox.Show("Please Check all fields", "Check your Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
    }
```

Comment: At first you need keep CurrentOrder in some property.

Comment: @Anton trying to come up with something but getting failed.

Comment: To change an order you use Update instead of Insert.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know reason why you use SqlCommand (probably better rewrite this application with modern ORM (EF or NHibernate)... but in your case for fix wrong behavior need do next:

```
    // need create domain type for keep order information
    // if need you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    public class Order {
            int      OrderID {get;set}
            DateTime Date {get;set}
            string   Customer_Name {get;set}
            int      Quality {get;set}
            string   Color {get;set}
            string   PCs       {get;set}
            string   Cutting {get;set}
            decimal  TotalYards {get;set}
    }

    // add property inside your form or viewmodel which is source for your form 
    private Order _currentOrder;
    public Order CurrentOrder
    {
        get{ return _currentOrder ;}
        set {
            if (_currentOrder!=value)
            {           
                 FillOrderDetailsBy(_currentOrder.Id)
            }
        }
    }

    // implement FillOrderDetails (
    void FillOrderDetails(int orderId)
    {
       var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select * from details", conn)
       var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

       while (reader.Read())
       {
            // add records to your dataTable which is sour
       }  
    }

    // change your newOrder button click handler
    void bntNewOrder_Click(sender, ars)
    {
         CurrentOrder = new Order(); // it will clear your dataGrid
    }

    // in case if in your domain you implmenet INotifyPropertyChanged
    // you can bind you controls to property of this class
    // this give you fill the power of WinForms dataBinding :))
    // for example in your constructor (after line with InitializeComponents())
    public YourFormName()
   {
    InitializeComponents();

    TxtBox_OrderID.DataBindings.Add("Text", CurrentOrder, "OrderID");
    dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add("Value", CurrentOrder, "Date");
    // etc with all controls which are related to Order
   }
```

Hope this approach will resolve your problem.

Comment: I put this in a class?

Comment: Just Order class... other code should be added to your form. Actually you need clean dataGrid when press AddNewOrder... so probably you need review your handler and just add code for clear dataGrid there. But more properly will use described approach

Comment: you mean this but this just clears the data not stores multiple products in 1 order number `private void Btn_New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateNew();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            txtbox_CusName.Clear();
            combo_Quality.SelectedIndex = -1;
            combo_Color.SelectedIndex = -1;
            updown_PCs.ResetText();
            combo_Cutting.SelectedIndex = -1;
            txtbox_CusName.Focus();

        }`

Comment: your question isn't clear for me... If you need save order details when you click newOrder button than you just need call code of SubmitButton handler before CreateNew();

Comment: I want to add multiple products in 1 Order number. 
when I hit "New Order" it should wipe out all the details that were in order number 1 and take new order details.

Comment: create new function void DeleteAllFromNewOrder()... and put sqlcommand "DELETE [MasterDatabase].[dbo].[Neworder]" instead of INSERT INTO... BUT attention this command will delete all records i NewOrder table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145274/discussion-between-patrick-and-anton).